# Best way to install python ubuntu (conda, system, env, or other)

Tags: python

I switched to Ubuntu 18.04 because I had enough of Windows. I read a few articles on options how to install python. I want to code some tools and scripts for Nuke (software, https://learn.foundry.com/nuke/developers/80/pythondevguide/nuke_as_python_module.html) and some gui stuff with pyside and pyqt.

As Ubuntu comes with py 2.7 and 3.6 preinstalled should I start adding packages to these pythons or should you keep them mint, in order to not damage them (and create problems with the system)?

I probably want to use python 2.7 and 3 simultaniously, is there a way to install modules for 2.7 and 3 at the same time (so I have the modules available regardless of the Python version)
There should be a reliable / robust way to update all packages of both pythons.

Why use conda or that virtualenv stuff and not python installed normally?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Adding packages won't "damage" them or the system beyond cluttering things up.

Using virtualenv is probably the easiest and beneficial because it makes clear exactly what packages one of your projects depends on. If you want someone else to run your code, you can just give them the output of `pip freeze` and they can get the necessary dependencies.

Regarding keeping packages in sync between python versions, there's not a standard way to do this because not all packages and package versions support both python 2 and 3. Furthermore, since you won't be using both on the same project, it doesn't seem to gain anything.

Answer (score 1):

You may install packages for your Python 2.7 and 3.6 by using `pip2` and `pip3` respectively.